# Does Yield Break return a value?

Tags: c#, vb.net, break, yield

I am converting a C# project into VB.net and need to understand C#'s Yield Break.  I know there are already questions concerning Yield Break on Stack Overflow, but I feel these questions are a little different.

1.) When you Yield Break does the function that contains it return a value to the caller?  If so, is it Null/Nothing, the default value for the type that the function is, or something else?

2.) When you Yield Break does the Iterator start over.  In other words, the next time the Iterator is called, will it return the first item in the collection again?

3.) What is the closest vb.net equivalent to Yield Break?  Exit Function?  Return Nothing?  Something Else?

Comment: `yield break` essentially informs the iterator that there are no more values. If it's the first item hit in the method, it will be _like_ returning an empty list. The method _itself_ still returns an `IEnumerable`, but if you try to iterate it it will be like iterating an empty list (that is, no iterations will occur). If you try to re-iterate the same `IEnumerable` result, it will call the method a second time. Depending on your logic, that might mean it will hit the `yield break` the same way (thus like an empty list) or perhaps this time you'll have it yield values. Can't comment on the VB.

Comment: I’d guess it’s `Exit Function`; [MSDN suggests `Exit Function` and `Return` both work](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dscyy5s0.aspx). (See **Technical Implementation**)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 1. When you Yield Break does the function that contains it return a value to the caller? If so, is it Null/Nothing, the default value for
>      the type that the function is, or something else?

No, it does not return a value. It just ends the enumeration. You can say, that it sets `IEnumerator.MoveNext()` return value to `false` and that's it.

> 2. When you Yield Break does the Iterator start over. In other words, the next time the Iterator is called, will it return the first item in
>      the collection again?

It all depends on how your method is written, but when you call the method which uses `yield` you're creating new instance of state machine, so it can return the same values again.

> 3. What is the closest vb.net equivalent to Yield Break? Exit Function? Return Nothing? Something Else?

"You can use an Exit Function or Return statement to end the iteration."

*from [Yield Statement (Visual Basic)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/hh156729.aspx)*

Answer (score 6):

`yield break;` does **not** yield an item as part of the `IEnumerable<T>` return value.

For example, the following gives you an empty enumerable:

```
IEnumerable<int> F()
{
     yield break;
}
```

This means `F().Count()` is 0.

Comment: While Marcin's answer was more complete, I wanted to give you a point because you most clearly answered the return type question.

Answer (score 2):

> When you Yield Break does the function that contains it return a value to the caller? If so, is it Null/Nothing, the default value for the type that the function is, or something else?

No, it stops the generation. No value is produced by `yield break;`. If you think of the iterator as a loop with a callback, it’s like `break`ing out of the loop.

> When you Yield Break does the Iterator start over. In other words, the next time the Iterator is called, will it return the first item in the collection again?

Yep, it’s called again, it produces a new iterator.

> What is the closest vb.net equivalent to Yield Break? Exit Function? Return Nothing? Something Else?

`Exit Function`.

Comment: 'Return' also works - iterators are the only place you can use a simple 'Return' within a function, and it means that the iterator has ended.